# Is there a Python equivalent to Erlang's pattern matching?

Tags: python, erlang

If I had a list of five things and I was only interested in the third and fifth of them, I would do this in Erlang:

```
[_First, _Second, Third, _Fourth, Fifth] = ListOfFiveElements,
```

The underscores means that I don't care about those variables and the end result is that Third and Fifth are bound to what's in the third and fifth place in that list. How do I best do the same in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Tuple unpacking and the convention is you can use a `_` for things you do not care about:

```
>>> ListOf5=['one','two','three','four','five']
>>> _,_,Third,_,Fifth=ListOf5
>>> Third, Fifth
('three', 'five')
```

This works for any sequence in Python as long as the total number is correct:

```
>>> _,_,Third,_,Fifth=[c for c in 'abcde']
>>> Third, Fifth
('c', 'e')
```

You can also construct the RH tuple to match the elements on the LH side of the assignment:

```
>>> Third,Fifth=ListOf5[2],ListOf5[4]
>>> Third,Fifth
('three', 'five')
```

And -- wait for it -- in Python 3 you can do a First, Second, All The Rest kind of tuple assignment:

```
>>> s1,s2,*s3='abcdefg'
>>> s1,s2,s3
('a', 'b', ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
>>> s1,*s2,s3='abcdefg'
>>> s1,s2,s3
('a', ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'g')
```

Comment: One important property of erlang's pattern matching is: if you have a bound variable and you try to match across this variable with different value, your match will fail. i.e.:
`Third = '3'; ListOf5=['one','two','three','four','five']; _,_,Third,_,Fifth=ListOf5`.
Must fail in erlang world, b/c '3' not equals to 'three'. I am not sure that this could be done with same elegance.

Answer (score 1):

Commas can be used to automatically unpack sequences in Python. Note the following example where I play around with assignment in different ways using a list.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a = x
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a,b,c,d,e = x
>>> c
3
>>> e
5
>>> a, = x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Basically as soon as you include a comma in the left-hand side of an assignment operator (`=`), it will automatically try to "unpack" the right-side operand.

So in the context of your specific example you could do something like this with your list:

```
_First, _Second, Third, _Fourth, Fifth = ListOfFiveElements
```

EDIT: Or as @drewk pointed out in his answer, just use `_` to "match" any unpacked element you do not need.

```
_, _, Third, _, Fifth = ListOfFiveElements
```

EDIT2: Oh and as a final note, if you use a comma on the *right-side* of an assignment operator, it will group all things on the right side into a tuple and then unpack them separately. Thus the following code will *not* work.

```
>>> _, _, Third, _, Fifth = ListOfFiveElements,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

This is because it makes a one-item tuple out of just `ListOfFiveElements`. The tuple is represented simply as `(ListOfFiveElements,)` and then when it's unpacked, it assigns `ListOfFiveElements` to `_` and then finds nothing more to assign to the remaining elements of the tuple on the left-hand side: `_, Third, _, Fifth`. Thus be careful where you include commas since Python will group these things into a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to match patterns using [unification](https://github.com/mrocklin/unification) in Python. This is essentially "bi-directional" pattern matching.

```
from unification import *

a,b = var('a'),var('b')
matched_pattern = unify(["unify","this1","pattern"],[a,"this",b])
if(matched_pattern):
    print("Value of a: "+matched_pattern[a])
    print("Value of b: "+matched_pattern[b])
else:
    print("The pattern could not be matched.")
```

This example prints the values of each variable:

```
Value of a: unify
Value of b: pattern
```